# creating a small web app with sinatra

Tags: web-applications, sinatra

I want to create a small web app with ruby and sinatra, can I get by fine without  Javascript? It doesn't need to have an advanced UI.

I'm just starting to learn ruby and don't know much about web stuff yet.
I'll learn JS after finishing the app but learning two languages at the same time is somewhat hard.

Can I easily add JS later to improve the UI?

Comment: JavaScript is in no way necessary to write a web application in Ruby/Sinatra. The only langauges you'll need are Ruby and HTML.

Comment: Ok cool, I'll get started that way then.

Comment: make sure to hop on the #sinatra channel on freenode. Many a helping hand is to be found there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! In fact, adding JavaScript afterwards is often the cleanest way to go about things, as it helps you cleanly separate content from behaviour and ensure that your website is accessible.

And, of course, you can always just do without JavaScript forever. It's usually nice, but it's not a necessity by any means.